# What is your preferred sorting order on answers list?

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting

Ordering by Votes seems good to me but i tend to read just the most voted questions and give points to them.
Reading a given question, what is your preferred sorting order on answers list and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newest first, almost always - for both questions and answers. That way I'm more likely to see new answers, instead of being drawn towards the ones which have already had more chance to get votes.

Comment: +1. I like newest and then sometimes view active every once in a while.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever's default.

Comment: thank you for this detailed and insightful answer.

Comment: @systempuntoout: I don't really fiddle with the default settings on SOFU simply because I find them good enough. I always go through all the answers, but the ones that have the highest number of votes are the ones that normally interest me the most. If I find something I consider useful, I'll upvote it no matter where it is in the list. Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

Ordering by Votes, but I read all the answers, anyway.